# removing a @property etc. generated by Storyboard and XCode

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to switch over to Storyboard from IB and code but got the following problem. Xcode created a `@property` with `@synthesize` and the `viewDidUnLoad` methods but I now don't need it and if I try to delete it, the code crashes. To make things worse, I in the meantime had connected it to a UIButton (I changed the class to allow this) by mistake. When it crashes, the code gives the message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key lock.'

The question is the following. Where does XCode put the code for this and what do I have to remove to get back to where I started from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a connection set up in your nib that uses that property. If you delete the property, you need to update your nib to not try and set it.

Comment: Yes, strange, I checked all that before and did take care to remove the button from the view hierarchy (worked it went) but when I clicked on the inspector for the 'DisplayViewController' at the top of the list it was still there. That feels a little strange because you would hav expected it to be removed. I am basically very impressed by Xcode4.2 but there are obviously still things to learn. Many thanks for this.